# Make a list with the most frequent tuple of a dictionary acording the first element

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, n-gram

I'm trying to make a list that contains the most frequent tuple of a dictionary acording the first element. For example:
If d is my dictionary:

```
d = {(Hello, my): 1,(Hello, world):2, (my, name):3, (my,house):1}
```

I want to obtain a list like this:

```
L= [(Hello, world),(my, name)]
```

So I try this:

```
L = [k for k,val in d.iteritems() if val == max(d.values())]
```

But that only gives me the max of all the tuples:

```
L = [('my', 'name')]
```

I was thinking that maybe I have to go through my dictionary and make a new one for every first word of each tuple and then find the most frequent and put it on a list, but I'm having trouble to translate that in a code.

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of a tie?

Comment: could you explain me why you output should be `L= [(Hello, world),(my, name)]`?? I don't understand you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achievable in O(n) if you just re-key the mapping off the first word:

```
>>> d = {('Hello','my'): 1, ('Hello','world'): 2, ('my','name'): 3, ('my','house'): 1}
>>> d_max = {}
>>> for (first, second), count in d.items():
...     if count >= d_max.get(first, (None, 0))[1]:
...         d_max[first] = (second, count)
...         
>>> d_max
{'Hello': ('world', 2), 'my': ('name', 3)}
>>> output = [(first, second) for (first, (second, count)) in d_max.items()]
>>> output
[('my', 'name'), ('Hello', 'world')]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import groupby

# your input data
d = {('Hello', 'my'): 1,('Hello', 'world'):2, ('my', 'name'):3, ('my','house'):1}

key_fu = lambda x: x[0][0]  # first element of first element,
                            # i.e. of ((a,b), c), return a

groups = groupby(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=key_fu), key_fu)
l = [max(g, key=lambda x:x[1])[0] for _, g in groups]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not just get the max on all the d values otherwise it just get the biggest value contained in your dictionary that is three in the specified case.
What I would do is create an intermediate list ( maybe this can be hidden ) that keeps in memory the first part of the key as second element, and the counter as first element. In this way you can just get the first element on the sorted list, to get the real max key.

Answer (score 0):

You have pairs of words and a count associated to each of them.  You could store your information in (or convert it to) 3-tuples:

```
d = [
  ('Hello', 'my', 1),
  ('Hello', 'world', 2), 
  ('my', 'name', 3),
  ('my', 'house', 1)
]
```

For each word in the first position, you want to find the word in 2nd position occurs the most frequently.  Sort the data according to the first word (any order, just to group them), then according to the count (descending).

```
d.sort(lambda t1,t2: cmp(t2[2],t1[2]) if (t1[0]==t2[0]) else cmp(t1[0],t2[0]))
```

Finally, iterate through the resulting array, keeping track of the last word encountered, and append only when encountering a new word in 1st position.

```
L = []
last_word = ""
for word1, word2, count in d:
   if word1 != last_word:
     L.append((word1,word2))
     last_word = word1

print L
```

By running this code, you obtain `[('Hello', 'world'), ('my', 'name')]`.